# Regex search from django.db.connection?

Tags: python, django

This works at the psql console:

```
SELECT * FROM chemical WHERE name ~* 'statin';
```

But not from inside Django:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
code = 'statin'
query = 'SELECT * FROM chemical WHERE name ~* %s'
print query
cursor.execute(query, (code,))
print cursor.fetchall()
```

This prints like this at the Django console:

```
SELECT * FROM chemical WHERE name ~* %s
```

But it returns an empty queryset.

How can I do regex search from inside Django? I guess I need to escape or unescape something.

Unfortunately `chemical` is a materialized view so I can't just use the Django ORM.

Comment: What does `code` mean? What's the value of this variable?

Comment: Sorry, added. Basically it's just a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need this:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
code = 'statin'
query = 'SELECT * FROM chemical WHERE name ~* {}'
print query.format(code)
cursor.execute(query.format(code))
print cursor.fetchall()
```

There's nothing to do with Django, you have to format the string properly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Django ORM can perform regex lookups for you, using the `__regex` lookup, as seen here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#regex

Or, as you are doing there, a case insensitive regex, with the `__iregex` lookup: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#iregex

Comment: I know, thanks, but I need to search a materialized view that's not actually one of my Django models.